# Printing all the nodes in the right subtree of a Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, recursion

I am fairly new to data structures, and recursion. So, I decided to try and implement a method that would print all the values of all the nodes of the right subtree (in ascending order, i.e: 50, 65, 72, 91, 99) in this given tree just as a learning experience.

Here is the tree that I am working with, visually.
[image: The tree itself]
And I have quite a few problems understanding how to recurse through the right subtree.

That's what I have tried doing so far (the actual method is at the bottom):

```
class BinarySearchTree:
    _root: Optional[Any]
    # The left subtree, or None if the tree is empty.
    _left: Optional[BinarySearchTree]
    # The right subtree, or None if the tree is empty.
    _right: Optional[BinarySearchTree]

def __init__(self, root: Optional[Any]) -> None:
    """Initialize a new BST containing only the given root value.
    """
    if root is None:
        self._root = None
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
    else:
        self._root = root
        self._left = BinarySearchTree(None)
        self._right = BinarySearchTree(None)

def is_empty(self) -> bool:
    """Return True if this BST is empty.

    >>> bst = BinarySearchTree(None)
    >>> bst.is_empty()
    True
    """
    return self._root is None

# That is what I have tried doing so far.
def print_right_subtree(self) -> None:
    """Print the right subtree in order

    >>> bst = BinarySearchTree(41)
    >>> left = BinarySearchTree(20)
    >>> left._left = BinarySearchTree(11)
    >>> left._right = BinarySearchTree(29)
    >>> left._right._right = BinarySearchTree(32)
    >>> right = BinarySearchTree(65)
    >>> right._left = BinarySearchTree(50)
    >>> right._right = BinarySearchTree(91)
    >>> right._right._left = BinarySearchTree(72)
    >>> right._right._right = BinarySearchTree(99)
    >>> bst._left = left
    >>> bst._right = right
    >>> bst.print_right_subtree()
    50
    65
    72
    91
    99
    """
    if self.is_empty():
        pass
    else:
        # I am not really sure what to do here... 
        # I have tried setting self._left = None, but that just made things even more complicated!
        print(self._root)
        self._right.print_right_subtree()
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated! Also, if any of you guys have a tutorial that I can follow, that would really great for a newbie like myself :).

Comment: What is the output you want?  There are a lot of ways to print a tree.  You trying to print them in DFS order?  BFS order?  Also, to keep your BST quick, it can be created, modified and deleted iteratively and not recursively.

Comment: I'd like to print the subtree in DFS in-order so that it will be ordered in ascending order.

Comment: print_left, print_current, print_right.  Thats how you would print in order then.  Also, do you have a rebalance method to clean up the tree?  If you choose to do it this way and not iteratively, you need to ensure that you rebalance the tree in order to keep lookups quick,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not asking for code itself, and rather for help to write your own code...

1. There are a million ways to do it. Some are more optimized. Some are faster to write. It all depends on what you need.
2. Here I think you need to understand what a tree is. Any of your subtree, is a tree by itself. So, you've got to understand that `print the right tree` does mean anything and everything. Only the right branch of each tree for instance ? Or all the tree of the first right branch ? Maybe the second branch ?
3. If I got it right (Da bum tss !), you want to print the right branch of the tree that's called root on your schema. Why not say `I want to print all the numbers above 41` instead ? That way, even if you want to print your tree beginning from a sub-tree, it would be really easy to do so !
4. You need to visualize what your algorithm would do. Here, you want to print all the numbers above 41 (the right branch of the main tree). Let me write you pseudo code for this (suppose you're already on your root node which has a value of 65 :

   - I want to write all the numbers in ascending orders...
   - My root is 65. My left is 50, my right is 91.
   - Which is the lowest ? 50. Does it have another branches ? No. Print it !
   - My root is still 65, my right is 91. My root is lower than my branch ? Print it ! And go to the right branch.
   - My main is now 91, my left is 72, my right 99.
   - Which is the lowest ? You got your recursion.

---

And even after all this, you could still choose to make another faster - to write, not to compute ! - solution. Gather all the values from the branch you need, and print the sorted values !

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful :)

Comment: Yes :) Thank a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the nodes in the right subtree, you just have to call your `print_tree` on the attribute of your tree corresponding to his right node.

First, you define a **print_tree** method:

```py
def print_tree(self) -> None:
    if self.is_empty():
        pass
    else:
        # you are free to do additional things here such as print node value or etc..
        self._left.print_tree()
        self._right.print_tree()
```

And then the **print_right_subtree** method:

```py
def print_right_subtree(self) -> None:
    self._right.print_tree() # which correspond to the print_tree of the _right attribute
```

Comment: print tree in your use case doesnt actually do anything except recursively call itself.  There is no actual print statement.  At least follow the OP and print something.  Also doing what you did will print a DFS design.  Is that what OP wants displayed?  Does OP have an order?

Comment: Thanks! I am kind of confused as to how your print_tree works. Does it first recurse all the way to the left, and only then all the way to the right down the tree? It could be extremely helpful if there was a way I could visualize what actually happens there.

Comment: Ah.. it depends... there are 3 type of parkour of tree:
infix, postfix, and prefix...

Comment: So, if we were to put the print statement in between the two, could you please lead me through what happens? Do we go all the way down to the left first and then go the to right? That's what confuses me the most..